# Can I hide a Java static method with a Kotlin companion object method?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to add some class-specific features to my app, and I'd like to have static methods on a class hierarchy where each class implements its own version of the method. I understand that treating these as overrides will produce behavior that can be hard to predict, but I intent to only call the methods with the classname as a prefix. So like

```
// Java
public class Base {
  public static int mapString(@NonNull String s) {
    int value = Child.mapString(s);
    if (value < 0) {
      return defaultValue;
    }
  }
}


// Kotlin
class Child: Base() {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic fun mapString(s: String): Int {
      return when {
        "a" -> 1
        else -> -1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Like this, Android Studio complains that there is an accidental override by Child.mapString(), but if I add the `override` keyword, then Android Studio complains that nothing was found to override.

Is it possible for me to hide a Java base class's static method from Kotlin?

Comment: "Android Studio complains that there is an accidental override by Child.mapString()"

It's simply a bug that should be reported then. There's no override.

Answer (score 0):

This is entire error:

```
Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (mapString(Ljava/lang/String;)I):
fun mapString(s: String): Int defined in com.example.Base
fun mapString(s: String): Int defined in com.example.Child
```

This might be an issue in how Kotlin works behind the scenes with Java interop. If you want to prevent the error you can add @JvmName annotation to have another name within JVM:

```
// Kotlin
class Child: Base() {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic 
    @JvmName("childMapString")
    fun mapString(s: String): Int {
      return when {
        "a" -> 1
        else -> -1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've ended up giving the subclass's method a different name. I was hoping to use the same name, since the desired behavior is the same, the subclass just has more specific information to act on.

Comment: @Greg did specifying custom `@JvmName` not help? That should change methods signature within JVM while letting you call them with their regular name in the IDE.

Comment: No, that didn't work. It looks like the base class recursively calls its own implementation. I think Java code uses the `@JvmName` version of the name, but Kotlin uses the "regular" name?